# Getting the number of occurrences between startDate and endDate in a EKRecurrenceRule

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, date

The premise is that there is a recurrenceRule instance that can hold a complex set of rules regarding recurrence during a week, month, year or longer.
I would like to find the number of occurences these rules yields.

#### Example rule:

```
Start date:   19 Sept 2012
End date:     24 Nov 2014
Recurrance:   EKYearlyRecurrence
monthsOfYear: Jan Mars July October
daysOfWeek:   Mon Thur Sat
```

Is it possible to do this in a simple way?

Comment: In your example above, do you want to know the number of times Monday occurs between the start & end date?

Comment: Nope. All occurences. That is Mondays, Thursdays and Saturdays between start and end.

Comment: Do you want if for all months or just the ones listed in your question?

Comment: Well for the months specified in the rule.
This is just an example of the type of complex rule that I might come across.
There might be other rules such as bi-weekly, as in every other week.

Comment: So if I understand this example, you want a count of how many time Mon, Thur, Sat occurred in Jan, Mar, Jul, Oct between 19 Sept 2012 to 24 Nov 2014?

Comment: In this example, yes. However what I need is a general way of getting the info. A way that applies to complex rules of any kind.

Comment: Before I can provide a suggestion, I have to figure out the answer for one example, and then adjust it for other example.

Comment: If it is unclear to you by now maybe you don't have the aptitude of understanding the problem at all. Shown it to several non geek friends, without explaining anything first and asked them to explain back to me what they think I want to do. They all got it spot on.
I think that you have actually figured out what I wish to do in this example. Uncertain why you keep on asking questions which are explained already.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think EKRecurrenceRule is meant to be used this way. EKRecurrenceRule is normally not used for such computations (you even cannot change the properties of the object - it's immutable). It is something like wrapper to hold information about recurrence, which is then used by EventKit framework. I actually doubt there is a built-in API to get exactly results you need. However, there are some useful methods in e.g. NSDateComponents, which can give you in combination with NSCalendar some useful results, but you would need to code a bit.